# Django 1.6, all() throws error: Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model

Tags: django, copy

I am having an exception in Django 1.6 with Python 2.7.13 (x86), and I don't know to to fix this. I already searched other posts for the answer, but to no avail.
I am stuck on this, and have been spinning my wheels for a while.

This is the line of code that throws the exception:

```
myNewClass.class_students = selectedClass.class_students.all()
```

Please see the complete code example below...

This is the error message that I am getting:

```
Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model.  Use MyApp.ClassStudents's Manager instead.
```

(For the above error message, my app is called 'MyApp'...)

It seems like all() does not work, is there anyway to fix this?
Can you guys please help me fix this or at least point me in the right direction...

Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
class Class(models.Model):

    courseNumber = models.IntegerField()
    courseName = models.CharField(max_length = 32)

    class_students = models.ManyToManyField(Student, blank = True, through = 'ClassStudent')

class Student(models.Model):

    studentName = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    overallStudentGPA = models.IntegerField()    

class ClassStudent(models.Model):

    myClass = models.ForeignKey(Class, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    myStudent = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    studentClassGrade = models.IntegerField()   

def copy_class(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for selectedClass in queryset:

        myNewClass = Class(courseNumber = selectedClass.courseNumber, courseName = selectedClass.courseName)

        myNewClass.courseNumber = selectedClass.courseNumber
        myNewClass.courseName = selectedClass.courseName

        # Throws an error:
        # Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model.  Use MyApp.ClassStudents's Manager instead.
        myNewClass.class_students = selectedClass.class_students.all()
```

Comment: You can save the myNewClass and then loop over `selectedClass.class_students.all()` and create new instances of `ClassStudent` which point to the new Class.

Comment: The reason why you can't set this directly is explained in the docs. [Unlike normal many-to-many fields, you can’t use add(), create(), or set() to create relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer that I came up with:

```
def copy_class(modeladmin, request, queryset):

    myNewClass = Class(courseNumber = selectedClass.courseNumber, courseName = selectedClass.courseName)

    myNewClass.courseNumber = selectedClass.courseNumber
    myNewClass.courseName = selectedClass.courseName

    myNewClass.save()

    for studentObj in selectedClass.class_students.all():

        oneClassStudentObj = ClassStudents.get(class = selectedClass, student = studentObj)

        tempStudentClassGrade = oneClassStudentObj.studentClassGrade

        tempClassStudent = ClassStudent(myClass = myNewClass, myStudent = studentObj, studentClassGrade = tempStudentClassGrade )

        tempClassStudent.save()
```

I was just wondering if there was a way to get the ClassStudent objects directly instead of having to use ClassStudents.get(...)? It works though...